# Model Factory returning the age of based on the birthdate just like this

Tags: php, laravel, factory, faker

[image]

I want to write a function that refers to that birthdate entry..

so far this is what i've done
[image]

but I get in the terminal
[image]

Comment: have you tried anything so far?

Comment: yeah definitely

Comment: Please post the code that you have tried. We can help you much better that way.

Comment: yeah changed it

Answer (score 0):

We can use below code.

```
$birthDate = '31-07-1983';
$data = [
    'age'=> call_user_func(function() use( $birthDate){
        return (date('Y') - date('Y', strtotime($birthDate)));
    })
];
print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering `age` is a calculated field and will change every day, this should not be data stored in your database, and therefore shouldn't need to be in your factory.

I'd remove the field from the database and the factory, and add an [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) to your model:

```
// Make sure birthdate is cast to a Carbon date.
protected $dates = [
    'birthdate',
];

// Define the "age" property accessor.
public function getAgeAttribute()
{
    return now()->diffInYears($this->birthdate);
}
```

With the accessor, you can access the field as a property:

```
$ci = App\CriminalInfo::find(1);
dd($ci->age);
```

You can also add it to the [`$appends` property](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json) if you want to see it in the model's array/json output.